# Shared preference always taking default value

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I always get default in my shared preference , why is this happening?
Here is the part where I insert value:

```
  holder.camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    RowData rd = getItem(position);   //get list_row from i
                    System.out.println("OnClick Camera");
                    Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    SharedPreferences prefs = (mContext).getSharedPreferences(
                              "com.oxtro.trustea", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = prefs.edit();

                       prefEditor.putString("crit_id_pref",String.valueOf(rd.criteria_id));


                        prefEditor.commit();

                    ((Activity)mContext).startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);


                }
            });
```

Here is where I retrieve its value, the value is always fetched as default rather than the needed one:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
                return;
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        System.out.println("File path is " + uri.toString());
        String path = getRealPathFromURI(uri);
        System.out.println("Real path is " + path);
        imageupload= new ImageUploadManager(ChapterActivity.this);
        imageupload.open();
         SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ChapterActivity.this);   
         String t_critid = preferences.getString("crit_id_pref", "DEFAULT");


        System.out.println("@OnActivityResult | shared pref crit id: "+t_critid);

    }
```

Comment: Why are you aclling your shared prefs in your second activity like this? PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ChapterActivity.this);

Comment: How are you getting the `mContext` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this call in your second activity too, to get the result:

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = (mContext).getSharedPreferences(
                          "com.oxtro.trustea", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 1):

In `onActivityResult`,

Change this:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ChapterActivity.this);
```

To this:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences("com.oxtro.trustea", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

You need to keep the **Preference** your referencing consistent. When you write to a **Preference** with one name, you need to read from it with the same name as well.