# Can't get values from SharedPreferences, logcat shows nothing

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I am having an issue with SharedPreferences that is kind of weird.

I have an Activity that holds a Fragment in a ViewPager. The fragment shows an icon and text. You can change the icon (check mark or cross, check mark is default) and text displayed in this fragment from another activity.

Now I want to save the text and chosen icon, so the fragment is shown with the same text and icon, even when you close the app and restart it later.

So I tried to achieve this with SharedPreferences, but when I tried it, my fragment showed me no text though I have default values set and the icon is always the cross, no matter what it was before and though the default icon should be the check mark.

I am saving the values in `onActivityCreated()` of my Fragment when it is created with the data the user inputted in the activity before.

Saving:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.fragmentdata.myapp", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

//Here I am getting the values I want to save from a bundle, city and country...

editor.putString("savedCity", city);
editor.putString("savedCountry", country);
editor.putString("fragmentSaved", "yes");

editor.apply();
```

Then, I am getting the values in `onCreate()` of my Activity that holds the Fragment:

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.fragmentdata.myapp", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

//adding fragment that was created with user input

String ifAdded = sharedPref.getString("addedFragment", "no");

    if(ifAdded.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        StatusFragment newFragment = new StatusFragment();
        newFragment.setArguments(extras);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addFragment(newFragment, extras.getString("city"));

        editor.putString("addedFragment", "no");

        editor.apply();
    }

    //Adding a saved fragment after restart

    String storedSave = sharedPref.getString("fragmentSaved", "no");

    if (storedSave.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
        String storedCity = sharedPref.getString("savedCity", "somecity");
        String storedCountry = sharedPref.getString("savedCountry", "somecountry");

        Bundle saves = new Bundle();

        StatusFragment savedFragment = new StatusFragment();

        saves.putString("city", storedCity);
        saves.putString("country", storedCity);

        savedFragment.setArguments(saves);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addFragment(savedFragment, saves.getString("city"));
    }
```

In the activity where the fragments data is created, I have this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.fragmentdata.myapp", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

                    editor.putString("addedFragment", "yes");

                    editor.apply();

                    fragmentHolder.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(fragmentHolder);
```

`bundle` has the values the user typed in, and `fragmentHolder` is the activity that holds the fragment.

I searched for answers in different questions here on stackoverflow, but none of them worked for me, like:

[Cannot get value from sharedpreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306908/cannot-get-value-from-sharedpreferences)

[Shared Preferences get lost after shutting down device or killing the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803838/shared-preferences-get-lost-after-shutting-down-device-or-killing-the-app)

[Shared Preferences reset data when app is force closed or device is restarted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353900/shared-preferences-reset-data-when-app-is-force-closed-or-device-is-restarted)

[SharedPreferences return only default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841488/sharedpreferences-return-only-default-value)

[SharedPreferences return only default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841488/sharedpreferences-return-only-default-value)

[Shared preference always taking default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355703/shared-preference-always-taking-default-value)

[SharedPreferences keep getting default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157963/sharedpreferences-keep-getting-default-value)

Sorry if I it is perhaps something trivial, but I haven't worked with Fragments much and I am using SharedPreferences the first time now.

I would be grateful for every helpful answer.

Comment: where you are retrieving the sharedpreference value ??? I cannot see any code for that

Comment: what is this condition supposed to do? `if(getResources().getString(R.string.pref_fragment_saved).equals("Yes")){` you know it will always be either `true` or `false` based on the value of `R.string.pref_fragment_saved` at `/values/strings.xml` which is not changable during runtime.

Comment: How we can access Shared prefernces like this is in your code?`SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Comment: I think there are two methods I knows which gives Shared Prefernce access `1.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); 2.context.getSharedPrefernces(PREF_NAME,MODE)`

Comment: @Anil Learn how to look up things in the [android dev docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getPreferences(int)), it's quite handy.

Comment: Oh! Sorry guys,I don't know we can access prefernces like this

Comment: Stop posting duplicate questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved now. I had to use `getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.fragmentdata.myapp", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);` and some of my variables in the bundles and preferences got mixed up. I corrected this and now it works fine :) Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up things that are stored in your `SharedPreference` and inside your applications resources (`strings.xml`)

`editor.putString(getString(R.string.pref_fragment_saved), "Yes");`

This line saves the string inside your preference XML, but then you try to read it as

`getResources().getString(R.string.pref_fragment_saved).equals("Yes")`

Which actually just reads the value `R.string.pref_fragment_save` from your `strings.xml`

The correct way of reading what you saved would be

`getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(getResources().getString(R.string.pref_fragment_saved), "defaultValue")`

Or a bit cleaner:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String key_frag_saved = getResources().getString(R.string.pref_fragment_saved);

String storedString = prefs.getString(key_frag_saved, "defValue");

if ( storedString.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") ) {...}
```

And the same way you would read the other saved values from your `SharedPreference` object instance.

Comment: Seems like something is wrong again :/ I get a Fragment with only default values. I updated my question with my new code.

Comment: @boehmP If I read correctly, you are reading the values in `onCreate()` of the Activity, which holds the fragment that saves the information? Did you relaunch the activity to see if the information was loaded? And are you certain that `onCreate` got called again? Add Log.i messages for loading and saving and check the order it is executed.

Comment: When I add the fragment I get the following Log outputs: I/Loading: Fragment loaded, I/Saving: Fragment saved, I/Saving: Fragment saved. It saves it twice for some reason and when I close the app and restart it, it has the same output but I have no text and the cross icon, though I have default values. I have absolutely no idea why everything is skipped?

Answer (score -1):

You wanted to use this

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = ...;
extras.putString("city", sharedPref.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.pref_saved_city), ""));
```

in your `onCreate` method